# Does python tornado RequestHandler coroutine safe?

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine

As we know, in threading, we have a concept call [thread-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

An when I use tornado coroutine, I don't know whether the self of the RequestHandler coroutine safe of not.

Here is my code:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write("Kingsoft API.")
        self.abc = 2
        yield self.gener()
        self.write(self.k)
        print self.k
        self.write("Kingsoft API.")
        return

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def gener(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        self.k = str(int(time.time()*100000))
        response = yield http_client.fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
```

Another question is, does my code would work expectantly?

Third other question is,
I only can use *self* to pass parameters and return values, but it's so ugly.
If I would love to use the AsyncHTTPClient inside some function but not in a callback way, do I have some other nice methods to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is in a "critical section" between "yield" statements -- you cannot be interrupted unless you execute "yield". So you don't need to worry about accessing "self" or any other value in between yields.

Parameter passing works normally with coroutines, but to return a value (in Python 2) raise gen.Return:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        self.write("Kingsoft API.")
        k = yield self.fn(2)
        self.write(k)

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def fn(self, arg):
        k = 2 * arg
        raise tornado.gen.Return(k)
```

In Python 3.3+ a simple "return k" also works.

Comment: Thanks, a nice example. Could you tell me how can I find more example for tornado web?

Comment: I have some example code here:

http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/

Besides that, of course, there's tornadoweb.org. The O'Reilly book "Introduction to Tornado" is sadly obsolete. I've been meaning to write more examples on my blog. I know Ben has made an effort recently to improve the example code on tornadoweb.org.